# What is the localization of the Sobel code inside OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to find the code for the Sobel() method in OpenCV since I'm learning C++ and I want to understand it's practical implementation in detail.

I used Visual Studio Code to browse the repo I imported from github, but then I was lost and I would appreciate method tips on how to find this kind of information.

I first searched for "sobel" and obtained in kernel_improc.cpp

```
GMat Sobel(const GMat& src, int ddepth, int dx, int dy, int ksize,
           double scale, double delta,
           int borderType, const Scalar& bordVal)
{
    return imgproc::GSobel::on(src, ddepth, dx, dy, ksize, scale, delta, borderType, bordVal);
}
```

I suppose that Sobel returns an object of type GMAT which is computed using GSobel, but I can't find where it is.

Can you explain to me where will I find where are the convolution operations and how they are called in different objects?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a look at [what is on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Asking for specific off-site resources is considered off-topic. On the other hand, asking for general guidelines to do something (_method tips_) might be considered as too broad. On your actual question: Have a look at [modules/imgproc/src/deriv.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/deriv.cpp) and search for `cv::Sobel`. That should be the proper starting point for your journey.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix an OpenCV version to talk about, otherwise it will be very hard for you to sync with me.  Let's use the most recent version: `OpenCV 4.1.2.tar.gz`.  You can find and download it easily.

First of all, C++ is a complex language, and it can transform from layers of codes into other codes.

Why OpenCV chooses to do it in this complex way of layers?  Because it has to handle different hardware!   If the computer comes with CV hardware, it can call hardware provided API to speed up computations.

Now, the function you are looking at, i.e. `imgproc::GSobel::on()`, is defined in:

```
   modules/gapi/include/opencv2/gapi/gkernel.hpp
```

as follows:

```
template<typename K, typename R, typename... Args>                                 
class GKernelType<K, std::function<R(Args...)> >                                   
    : public detail::MetaHelper<K, std::tuple<Args...>, R>                         
    , public detail::NoTag                                                         
{                                                                                  
public:                                                                            
    using InArgs  = std::tuple<Args...>;                                           
    using OutArgs = std::tuple<R>;                                                 

    static R on(Args... args)                                                      
    {                                                                              
        cv::GCall call(GKernel{K::id(), K::tag(), &K::getOutMeta, {detail::GTypeTraits<R>::shape}});
        call.pass(args...);                                                        
        return detail::Yield<R>::yield(call, 0);                                   
    }                                                                              
};
```

See, a lot layers of code transform: `static R on()`, where `R` is a general class and defines lots of kernels.  In your case, `R` == `imgproc::GSobel`

Overall, again, as I said, C++ is complex.  So, please be patient, and try to find all symbols of GSobel and sobel/Sobel, carefully expand all macros....  If you want to try the hard way, I can only lead you here.

An easy way would be to compile the library in debug mode, and use a debugger to trace into OpenCV code.  You will need a decent debugger, to parse C++ complex syntax, plus preprocessor macros.